# Regex to add prefix

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
ab ab-alfa beta gamma ab-delta
```

I would like to add the prefix "ab-" to every word, except for the words that already have it and except for the word "ab" (the first one).

I mean, I would get this result:

```
ab ab-alfa ab-beta ab-gamma ab-delta
```

You know indicate a regex and explain it?

--
edit

So far I've tried this ([link](http://regexr.com?38271)):

```
\b(?!ab)\w+\b
```

But I don't think I understand how the negation works.

Comment: Have *you* tried to write such a regex and can *you* try to explain us why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: They don't look like words. What is a word?

Comment: Do you not want `ab-` to be prepended to the **first word** or any word that is **ab**?  We need a better explanation of what you consider a *word*.

Comment: @Sam, you forgive me if I don't know how to explain it perfectly. 
For "word" I mean, in this case, the separation provided by the space. 
Look at the result that I have posted.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I modified the initial message.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/wP5fW6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<![^ ])(?=[^ ])(?!ab)
```

with the replacement `ab-`.

`(?<![^ ])(?=[^ ])` will search for the boundary of the beginning of a word (which is defined to be a sequence of non-space characters).

In general, given a character class for "word character"s C, a general "word boundary" (similar to `\b`) would be:

```
(?:(?<!C)(?=C)|(?<=C)(?!C))
```

The boundary for the beginning of a "word" would be:

```
(?<!C)(?=C)
```

The boundary for the end of a "word" would be:

```
(?<=C)(?!C)
```

This ensures that "word boundary" is not found on empty string, and a "word boundary" is found if a "word character" is at the beginning or the end of the string.

---

Note that `(?<= )(?! )` at first glance may look like an equivalent pattern to `(?<![^ ])(?=[^ ])`, but **it is not**, since it fails to match the beginning of a word when the word appears at index 0 in a string.

Also, don't try to shorten it to `(?<![^ ])(?!ab| )`, it will return a match when the string is empty.

Comment: It seems to fail to match any word that starts with ab.  So abcde ab-alfa beta gamma ab-delta --> abcde ab-alfa ab-beta ab-gamma ab-delta

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: It looks like what the OP wants, though. The example is too lacking to determine whether `abcde` is to be prefixed or not.

Comment: I interpreted his request differently.

Comment: thanks (and sorry if I reply late), it was just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the regex

```
(?<!ab-)(?!\bab\b)\b\w+\b
```

And this for the replacement string

```
ab-$&
```